# xCode 5.1.1 is always indexing

Tags: ios, xcode, ide

It is a couple of day that my xcode started to index continuously. It's really annoying because the UI locks for seconds while i'm writing. I'm going mad.
I didn't change any specific build settings. I can't recall no change that could be the cause of the problem

[image: Indexing | Processing files]

My project as 130 classes. I'm using cocoapods and my pod file contains 20 pods.

I tried to reboot xcode and clean up the project without notice no improvements.

I have a macbook pro with SSD disk. 8GB of RAM

The indexing is slow when the system is not using swap memory and the cpu is 20-30% used.

[image: Memory]

Any ideas?